# iphone custom datepicker

Tags: iphone, user-interface

Is there any datepicker UI elements that I can use on my iphone application? Native one is found to be too big.

Comment: make your own or search github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the right question is why is it too big? Apple has done a pretty good job of making a set of controls that apply for most circumstances, look stylish, and are usable by the user.

The default control is the size of the iPhone keyboard, and it was made this way for a very good reason: all elements are easily viewable and selectable by touch. If you have a lot of UI elements making life difficult, consider displaying the selected date/time in a label and edit it in a modal dialog.